# SQL Query - condition to match at least 4 values from 5

Tags: sql, relational-division

I am new to `SQL`, and I need a help writing a query (attached photo Diagram)

**Summary:**

IG School system that requires students to choose 5 studying subjects in specific studying sessions, then the query should result:

1)  Already available groups that has the chosen subjects;

or

2)  Groups that at least comply with 4 chosen subjects, and also return the subject with no match.

**Tables:**

```
Sessions -----> Like Semesters
Groups   -----> Like classes that has schedule
```

I already wrote a query but with no condition for the available groups with only 4 matching subjects, return only groups that match all 5 subjects (the problem), which as below:

```sql
    SELECT Group_Subjects.Group_ID, Groups.Name as Groups_Name,  Subject_Schedule.ID as Subject_Schedule_ID,Subjects.ID Subjects_ID,
    Subjects.Name AS Subjects_Name,Sessions.Name AS Sessions_Name
    FROM   Groups 
    INNER JOIN Group_Subjects ON Groups.ID = Group_Subjects.Group_ID 
    INNER JOIN Subject_Schedule ON Group_Subjects.Subject_Schedule_ID = Subject_Schedule.ID 
    INNER JOIN Subjects ON Subject_Schedule.Subject_ID = Subjects.ID
    INNER JOIN Sessions ON dbo.Groups.Session_ID = dbo.Sessions.ID   
    where Groups.Session_ID=13 and  Subjects.ID in (16,117,125,126,127)
    order by Group_Subjects.Group_ID,Subjects_Name
```

Photo Diagram

[image: Here]

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. I haven't found the diagram you said you provided. Provide more info.

Comment: I did not fully understand your question, but I *think* is a relational division. Please see the "see also" column on the right...

Answer (score 0):

you can grouped the result of selected groups (group by) and filtered it by number of occurence of subject (having count(subject)>=4)  some thing like this :

```
SELECT Group_Subjects.Group_ID, Groups.Name as Groups_Name,  Subject_Schedule.ID as Subject_Schedule_ID,Subjects.ID Subjects_ID,
    Subjects.Name AS Subjects_Name,Sessions.Name AS Sessions_Name
    , **count (Subjects.ID)** 
    FROM   Groups 
    INNER JOIN Group_Subjects ON Groups.ID = Group_Subjects.Group_ID 
    INNER JOIN Subject_Schedule ON Group_Subjects.Subject_Schedule_ID = Subject_Schedule.ID 
    INNER JOIN Subjects ON Subject_Schedule.Subject_ID = Subjects.ID
    INNER JOIN Sessions ON dbo.Groups.Session_ID = dbo.Sessions.ID   
    where  Subjects.ID in (16,117,125,126,127)
    **group by** Group_Subjects.Group_ID, Groups.Name as Groups_Name,  Subject_Schedule.ID as 
    Subject_Schedule_ID,Subjects.ID Subjects_ID,
    Subjects.Name AS Subjects_Name,Sessions.Name AS Sessions_Name
    **having count (Subjects.ID) >= 4**
```

Comment: Really thank you, but this doesn't return the unmatched subject name or id

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well (though I am not 100% sure), your requirements include:
 1. Select "groups" that match at least 4 of 5 given "subjects".
 2. Don't include "groups" that match less than 4 of the 5 given
    "subjects".

For that you can run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    gr.name, sub.name
FROM
    groups           gr  JOIN
    group_subject    gs  ON gs.group_id = gr.id JOIN
    subject_schedule ss  ON ss.id = gs.subject_schedule_id JOIN
    subject          sub ON sub.id = ss.subject_id  
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            g.id, COUNT(*) num_subjects
        FROM
            groups           g  JOIN
            group_subject    gs  ON gs.group_id = g.id JOIN
            subject_schedule ss  ON ss.id = gs.subject_schedule_id JOIN
            subject          sub ON sub.id = ss.subject_id  
        WHERE
            sub.id IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') AND
            g.id = gr.id
        GROUP BY gr.id
        HAVING num_subjects >=4
    )
ORDER BY 
    gr.name, sub.name;
```

Adding to that, `subject_schedule` seems to be referring to `sessions`. At the same time, `groups` also refers to `sessions`.
That can lead to problems in case that data is not consistent. For that reason I am not including 'sessions' in my query as the other tables have all the information needed for your use case.

I have created an example model of your schema to test that query (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    id                   VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 TEXT,
    session_id           VARCHAR(7) REFERENCES sessions
);
CREATE TABLE group_subject (
    id                   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id             VARCHAR(5) REFERENCES groups,
    subject_schedule_id  INTEGER REFERENCES subject_schedule,
    description          TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE subject_schedule (
    id                   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 TEXT,
    session_id           VARCHAR(7) REFERENCES sessions,
    subject_id           VARCHAR(1) REFERENCES subject
);
CREATE TABLE subject (
    id                   VARCHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id                   VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 TEXT
);
```

Hope it helps.